I can't alter the flyway history table with Flyway
When I clone my prod db and prod flyway to a local docker instance and start my local spring boot application, I'm getting this error (names have been sanitized):

Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'installed_on', table 'a.b.flyway_schema_history'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

This will become an issue when I deploy to prod.  Prod flyway has 2 entries in the history table.  Test flyway has 13.
This problem is solved by running the SQL below.  I don't have production access, only the service account that I'm using flyway with.
ALTER TABLE a.b.flyway_schema_history
ADD CONSTRAINT DF_flyway_schema_history_installed_on DEFAULT GETDATE() FOR installed_on;

I have several scripts already in resources/db/migration that I've executed in Test already.  Prod is old and will need the SQL above to execute first.
I've tried adding B1__update_flyway_history.sql to my scripts and have added
spring:
  flyway:
    baseline-on-migrate: true
    out-of-order: false
    schemas: a
    baseline-version: 0

to my application.yaml file.  I can't get the flyway_schema_history updated.  If I cannot change it with baseline, then how can I do this?  Advice will be welcomed.
I have considered adding the SQL as a first script and incrementing the subsequent scripts, and manually deleting the Test flyway_schema_history to create a new history.  Is there a better way?

Seems related to https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/3876

hmm.  according to that post, I could bump the flyway version way down and add my alter table script. then bump the version back to latest again.
